# SEO URL with multiple files.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

I have many hours trying to find the solution here but none looks like what I'm looking for ... I will give a long explanation and possibly someone will serve you what I have and not need to change it.

Table `pages`

[image]

Table `products`

[image]

File `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?route=$1&url=$2 [NC,L]
```

If I put in the browser: `example.com/pages/contact`

really we are in: `example.com/pages.php?route=pages&url=contact`

In the file `pages.php`

```
<?php require_once 'inc/header.php'; ?>
 <section>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <?php
    $route= $_GET["route"];
    $url = $_GET["url"];
    $results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM $route WHERE url='$url'");
    foreach ($results as $row) { ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <h2><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h2>
   </div> 
   <?php } ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
<?php require_once 'inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

The same goes for `products.php`, is the same code as all get by `_GET`

**The problem I have:**

I want to eliminate the `$route` in the URL, I want the URL looks like this:

`example.com/contact` or `example.com/acer-one`

Is how to do this, if the two designs are identical, ie, put everything in `index.php`, the problem is I need to use the two files to display a design or another.

Where do I begin? I modified it? It is a project I'm starting from scratch, so I can change anything.

Comment: I would suggest making all of them 'pages', and add some sort of 'type' column to your pages table. That type can then determine which template you need to use to render the actual page.

Comment: @Pevara I thought of that possibility, but it would be the same or not? since it would have to add "type" to the URL

Comment: no, not to the url, to the table. And based on the url that is stored in your db you can see which type it is and therefore which template to use. One controller, one table, no duplication of logic.

Comment: @Pevara Could you help me with some sample code?

Comment: Sure, I've posted an answer in an attempt to clarify what I mean. Feel free to ask if it still doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following example structure:

Start by adding a table "routes" that just contains each possible url, along with a type (and every field that both pages and products have in common). This would also mean you can remove the `url` column (and the other common columns) from the pages and products table (or perhaps remove the table all together, if no relevant data is left). Something like this:

```
TABLE routes
id   route     type      name
1    contact   page      Contact
2    acer1     product   Acer 1
```

Add your main controller, probably index.php, that looks something like this:

```
<?php
    $url = isset($_GET["url"]) ? $_GET["url"] : 'home';
    // you should probably use prepared statements here, but that is a different topic
    $result = DB::query("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE url='$url'" LIMIT 1);

   if (! $result) {
     // 404
   }

   // any other common logic can go here, like header and stuff
   require_once 'inc/header.php';

   // now load the type specific page
   include $result['type'] . '.php';

   // and continue with the shared logic
   require_once 'inc/footer.php';
```

Change your .htaccess to send everything to index.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now you only need a single path element and no type in the url. And you could add a page with url `home` for when no path elements are provided. Plus you have the possibility to still work with deep links 'my/awesome/deep/linked/page', all you have to do as add that url to your routes table. Inventing a new page type would be very easy as well, just add a 'my-new-type.php' file for the custom logic and you are set.

The key is to have a single point of entry into your application, a so called frontcontroller. And keep your code DRY, Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: It seems a very good option, I hope to achieve this and I commented in minutes (finished eating) hahaha

Comment: It was just what I needed, corrected some parts of the code example but in the end it succeeds! Thank you very much! Opened my mind to move forward.

Comment: And achieve what you discussed me, the problem is that I can not add more information to the URL: example.com/products/edit

Comment: How is that? Doesn't the $url contain 'products/edit'? Or is there a query issue?

Comment: Add this to .htaccess http://i.imgur.com/aHyQuPX.png now I have up to 3 levels more: products/edit/edit/edit/ but how to manage files? that is, to be in products / edit as I have to do the "include" do not understand.